# "If you burn a zombie, you'll only get a flaming zombie chasing you"?

Tags: story-identification, zombie

A friend of mine thought one of the rules in Zombieland was **"Don't burn a zombie - it only gets you being chased by a flaming zombie"** or something like that. But he re-saw the movie, and didn't find anything like that.

We searched the internet, but couldn't find anything like that. Anyway, it seems like a really good quote to just have been made up for him, so here I am, asking...

Is there any story/book/movie/series with a quote like that?

Comment: Not in Game of Thrones. The ice zombies don't like that!

Comment: Well it definitely *sounds* familiar, and Zombieland seems like the kind of zombie flick to say it...  Perhaps I read something like this in Max Brooks' [Zombie Survival Guide](https://www.amazon.ca/Zombie-Survival-Guide-Complete-Protection/dp/1400049628)...? but I don't think it was used in WWZ...

Comment: I know this one too and Zombieland was the first movie that came to my mind. Can't be Zombie Survival Guide because I didn't read that.

Comment: Are we sure it wasn't in World War Z the *book*, because that sounds like it and it sounds familiar to me and I also have not read the Zombie Survival Guide.

Comment: I could swear I heard this exact quote too! Unfortunately, no idea where. Anybody knows a game where zombies won't burn to death in seconds?

Comment: I can't find the quote in World War Z. Only one mention of "flaming" and all of the mentions of "fire" are about guns or buildings catching fire.

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt: "Burn, Zombie, Burn!"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burn_Zombie_Burn

Comment: I heard this quote too, bu I think it's from a game. I would suspect Dead Island or Dying light (the only zombie games I played - ok I played Left 4 Dead too, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't there).

Comment: See TV Tropes: [Infernal Retaliation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InfernalRetaliation)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Nope, haven't played that.
Ajedi32: Sounds about right, although it doesn't ring a bell either.

Comment: This sounds familiar to me too, but if not the Zombie Survival guide, I'm thinking maybe something that almost spoofs the original zombie genre, maybe Shawn of the Dead or possibly My Name is Bruce?

Comment: Does your friend frequent this site? I know I've seen that sentiment on here a couple times. Can't find the questions or answers at the moment though...

Comment: It _might_ be [this Cracked article?](http://www.cracked.com/blog/7-famous-zombie-movie-weapons-that-would-get-you-killed/)

Comment: In WWZ (the film) the only comment about burning was by the captain in S. Korea who said "we like to burn 'm when we can".

Comment: Mandela effect?

Comment: Off topic, but using a superior incendiary agent that burns at extremely high temperatures may mitigate the problem. Napalm, thermite, and the like should cause more rapid and thorough thermal decomposition to the point that the reanimated corpse is no longer mobile within a minute or less.

Comment: BigBangTheory has a lot of discussions of that type..

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It may have been Max Brooks's *Zombie Survival Guide*. From the section on **Weapons and Combat Techniques**:

> Finally, at five meters, we used the last bit of fuel in the flamethrower! The sons of bitches lit up like torches but just wouldn’t stop! One of them grabbed [Name Withheld], setting him on fire as it bit through his neck. I saw the rest of those things surround him as we took off for the jungle, a mob of burning bodies squatting down to tear another screaming human torch apart.

Also, from the **Fire** section:

> Flesh — human, undead, or otherwise — takes a long time to burn. In the minutes or hours before a blazing zombie succumbs, it will become a walking — or to be perfectly accurate, a shambling — torch. Several cases have been recorded in which burning ghouls have done more damage, even caused more deaths, than they would have with only their fingernails and teeth.

Lastly (and I don't have access to the book, so I can't verify where it showed up), TV Tropes mentions under [Infernal Retaliation](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InfernalRetaliation) as also being in *Zombie Survival Guide*:

> "Established wisdom for modern zombie hunters: The only thing worse than a horde of zombies is a horde of flaming zombies."

They also note that mention of the danger of flaming zombies does come up in *World War Z* as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the book of *World War Z* includes that.  I'll re-read tonight and let you know.  I've no idea about the film, because I didn't watch it on principle.

Comment: @Graham I remember that bit from the book as well. I felt the same way about the movie as did, but ended up seeing it at some point anyway. You are missing nothing but disappointment.

Comment: @Broklynite Thanks for confirmation that I made the right call on that one. :)